# Reading and storing a specific part of a line in python

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to read this text file line by line and store specific information from the line to use it after in my program. There are 5 pieces of information and 4 of them are separated with "_". The last one is separated with ":".

Txt file sample:

```
Shahran_1_True_True:61666.67
Shahran_1_True_True:61666.67
Pardis_2_True_True:18333.33
Shahrake Qods_2_True_True:30083.33
Shahrake Gharb_2_True_True:233333.33
```

For example, I need to store Shahran, Pardis and Shahrake Qods in a list. I can read the lines but I can't separate the information. Can anyone show me a way of doing this?

Comment: `split` method ? `'Shahran_1_True_True:61666.67'.split('_')[0]`

Comment: Could also use `csv.reader` with `_` as the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
my_list = []

with open('my_text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        my_list.append(line.split('_')[0])    #index [0] to get the first element

my_list = list(set(my_list))    #get only unique names
print(my_list)
```

Output

```
['Shahran', 'Shahrake Gharb', 'Shahrake Qods', 'Pardis']
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to split each line at `_` and `:`. You probably want to store all the information as a `list` of `dict`s.

Be sure to read the documentation on the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

```py
records = []

with open('locations.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        column1, column2, column3, remaining = line.split("_")
        column4, column5 = remaining.split(":")
        record = {}
        record["column1"] = column1
        record["column2"] = column2
        record["column3"] = column3
        record["column4"] = column4
        record["column5"] = column5
        records.append(record)
```

`records` is now a list made up of 6 `dict`s. To get to the strings stored within, you can access them like so:

```py
print(records[0]["column1"])
```

Output:

```py
Shahran
```

Comment: What is record = {}  for?

Comment: That creates an empty `dict`. It is the same thing as `record = dict()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict